# How to create relation one to many between IdentityUser model and another model (Keys type difference)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create relation one to many beetwen IdentityUser model(inherits from `IdentityUser` class) and Comment model but I get an error: `The relationship from 'Comment.WebAppUser' to 'WebAppUser.Comments' with foreign key properties {'UserId' : int} cannot target the primary key {'Id' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.` Problem is that IdentityUser model uses a `string` as primary key but in Comment model type of foreign key which is id of user is `int`.

The question is: How should I resolve this conflict? Should I change type of IdentityUser primary key for int (I know that i can do it, **but won't that create problems because of the `IdentityUser` base class and its structure?**) or maby convert forgein key for string?

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public WebAppUser WebAppUser { get; set; }
}

public class WebAppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }       
}
```

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
       .HasOne<WebAppUser>(w => w.WebAppUser)
       .WithMany(c => c.Comments)
       .HasForeignKey(w => w.UserId);
```

If the option is to change the primary key of the WebApp User table, let me know what the consequences are and what and where I would have to change/add in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Fk` to string and changing the type of `primary key` of the `WebAppUser` are both available methods, But If you choose to change the type of `PK` in `WebAppUser`, you need to modify it according to the following code：

`Model`

```
public class WebAppUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

Change:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
```

to

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<WebAppUser,IdentityRole<int>,int>
```

`Startup.cs`

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<WebAppUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Now you change the type of pk to `int` successfully.

In my opinion, Change FK to string is easier than change PK to `int` in `IdentityUser`.

More details you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0)